How to have VS Code/TypeScript syntax highlight code inside of quotes?
Is there a way to have VS Code syntax highlight code inside of quotes (template quotes or regular quotes)?
Example, I want vscode to syntax highlight the code var x = "hello" that are in the quotes:
var value = `var x = "hello"`;

Or could I write code normally so VS Code syntax highlights it and then later get the string value of the functions?
class Test {
    
   test() {
      var x = 10;
   }

   showTestAsString() {
      var value = this.test.toString();
      console.log(value); // "function test() { var x = 10; }"
   }
}

I did the code above in the console and it returns this:
'function () { [native code] }'

I remember when it used to print out all of the function code.
If I open the console and declare the function inline it does print out the code:
let x = () => { return 10 }; console.log(x);
() => { return 10 }

If I leave the parentheses off of the method it seems to return the string but if I concatenate it it shows it's a function:
let val = this.showTestAsString; console.log(val)
ƒ showTestAsString() {
    var value = this.test.toString();
    this.log(value);
  }

let val = this.showTestAsString; console.log("test = " + val)
test = function () { [native code] }

According to MDN it is returning native code because I've used bind() on the function (my code adds it). So now I have to try to unbind it.

Yes, you could do exactly that.

a template string is not always JavaScript code, so how should VSC decide when it is a text string and when it is a string with JavaScript code.

@rioV8 indeed. that's why I was wondering if there was a way to inform vscode to format the code in the string as JS. you know how we have three backticks and then the language name? I was wondering if there's a directive(?) for template string or regular strings

you might try to adjust the JavaScript Textmate grammar and based on some signal/format you design instruct the Grammar to inject JavaScript as the language for the next block between string delimiters
